# htlatex with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, htlatex

I have a latex file with snippet

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\@ifpackageloaded{tex4ht}{%
%\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{xcolor}
%\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}
\usepackage[tex4ht]{hyperref}
}{%
%\usepackage{xcolor}  % [pdftex] explicit specification works for pdflatex only 
%\usepackage{graphicx}% [pdftex] explicit specification works for pdflatex only 
\usepackage{hyperref}% driver [hpdftex] is autodetected 
}

...

\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
%\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}


\begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[>=latex, scale=0.5]
\matrix[row sep=10mm, column sep=18mm] {
                     & \node(L)[op]{$\Lt$};   &                     \\
                     &                        &                     \\
                     & \node(S)[op]{$\It[]$}; &                     \\
\node(I)[op]{$\It$}; &                        & \node(R)[op]{($\Rt$)}; \\
}; % matrix 
%\path[->] (L) edge[loop above]  node [sloped, above] { $\eql,\neql$ } (L);
%\path[->] (R) edge[dashed] node [sloped, above] {($\le,] (I) edge         node [sloped, above] { $\le,] (R) edge[dashed] node [sloped, below] {($\round$)} (I);
\path[->] (I) edge[bend left]         node [sloped, above] { $\str$  } (S);
\path[->] (S) edge[bend left]         node [sloped, below] { $\ind$  } (I);
\path[->] (S) edge[]                  node [sloped, below] { $\type$ } (I);
\path[->] (R) edge[bend left, dashed] node [sloped, above] {($\str$) } (S);
\path[->] (S) edge[bend left, dashed] node [sloped, above] {($\real$)} (R);
\path[->] (L) edge[bend left]         node [sloped, above] { $\str$  } (S);
\path[->] (S) edge[bend left]         node [sloped, above] { $\logic$} (L);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

applying htlatex I receive in the log file:

```
[20] [21] [22

]
l.832 --- TeX4ht warning --- \halign translated into linear text ---
)
Runaway preamble?
\pgf@matrix@padding \cr  & \node (L)[op]{$\Lt $}; & \\ & & \\ & \node \ETC.
! File ended while scanning preamble of \TeXhalign.
 
                \cr }
 ...tml,uni-html4,2,svg.a.b.c.\input  langS.tex
```

I am pretty sure, that the warning is related with the error.

Can anyone explain what happened and above all, what to do??

Update: in the meantime, i found out, that without the tabular environment, all works fine. 
But still it is not at all clear what happened and how to recover.

Comment: are you loading TikZ at some point ? and `\begin{document}`? Because tikz already  loads `xcolor` and `graphicx`

Comment: I updated and showed now the load of tikz. I discovered, that i do not need xcolor or graphicx and removed it. - Unfortunately, does not work either.

Comment: Please, try to post some code which could be (or not) compiled but which shows the same error. `\begin` and `\end{document}` are missing, `op` style is not defined just like `\Lt`, ...